# convert double to float

Tags: java

I've seen an example where the following code is used to convert a double to a float:

```
Double.valueOf(someDouble).floatValue()
```

I would just do it like

```
(float)someDouble
```

Is there any advantage to using the former?

Comment: None whatsoever. It creates a `Double` object, which is a waste of memory, and calls a method, which does the same typecast you did in one operation. Completely pointless.

Comment: Perhaps the author of that code has learned that casts should be avoided and is now mindlessly applying that idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at the implementation of `Double`'s `floatValue()` :

```
/**
 * Returns the value of this {@code Double} as a {@code float}
 * after a narrowing primitive conversion.
 *
 * @return  the {@code double} value represented by this object
 *          converted to type {@code float}
 * @jls 5.1.3 Narrowing Primitive Conversions
 * @since JDK1.0
 */
public float floatValue() {
    return (float)value;
}
```

It looks like it behaves exactly like your casting. Therefore there's no advantage to using it.

Comment: Except for wastefully creating a `Double` object ... which is a *disadvantage*.

Comment: @EJP That's true.